# Get sum of an entire row, diagonal & entire column in two dimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So my two dimensional array looks like this:

```
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
   ------------------
   0| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1| 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 <-- Sum of this Row is 1
   2| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   3| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   4| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   5| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   6| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 <-- Sum of this diagonal row is also 1
   7| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
          ^ Sum of this column is also 1
```

Now I can get sum of the row by just doing:

```
 $sumRow  = array_sum($board[1]); //Is equal to 1
```

But I can not figure out how to get sum of the column or diagonal without doing the loop. I know I will need to use loop to get the sum of diagonal, but is there a way to get sum of column without loop? Or as efficient as possible?

```
 $sumCol  = array_sum($board[][2]); //Something like this
 $sumDiag = ?
```

Comment: Well you could try this, Stick this array into a class and make methods to set positions, keep a variables for each row that represent the sum, when setting a cell you only need need to count the new setted value with the sum of that row, (also diagonal), when requesting a sum value the execution time will be Θ(1). The only time when you will have Θ(n) is when you create the gameboard and go over each row. But the memory usage will increase by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of how to get sum of the row, column and diagonal. The idea is to split the array like in this examples:

```
diagonal +1           diagonal -2

0 |0 0 0 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0
0 |0 1 0 0 0 0 0     _0_0_1_0_0_0  0 0
0 |0 0 0 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0 0 0| 0 0
0 |0 0 0 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0 0 0| 0 0
0 |0 0 0 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0 0 0| 0 0
0 |0 0 0 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0 0 0| 0 0
0 |0_0_0_0_0_0_0_     0 0 0 0 0 0| 0 0
0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0 0 0| 0 0
```

That way is easy to get diagonal sum of any diagonal with simple array_walk:

```
$row_sum = function( $array, $row ) { 
    return array_sum( $array[$row] ); 
};

$column_sum = function( $array, $column ) {     
    return array_reduce( $array, function( $r, $i ) use ( $column ) {
        return $r += $i[$column];       
    });
};

/**
 * @param int $diagonal ( positive and negative )
 */
$diagonal_sum = function( $array, $diagonal ) {

    $slice = array_map( function($i) use ($diagonal) {
        return $diagonal < 0 ? array_slice($i, 0, $diagonal) : array_slice($i, $diagonal);  
    }, $diagonal > 0 ? array_slice($array, 0, -$diagonal) : array_slice($array, abs($diagonal)));

    array_walk( $slice, function( &$item, $key ) {
        $item = $item[$key];
    });

    return array_sum( $slice ); 
};


$array = array_map( function() { return array_fill( 0, 8, 0 ); }, array_fill( 0, 8, 0 ) );
$array[1][2] = 1;

echo $row_sum( $array, 1 ); 
echo $column_sum( $array, 2 );  
echo $diagonal_sum( $array, 1 );
```

Answer (score 5):

Just try with [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) (PHP >= 5.5.0):

```
$sumCol = array_sum(array_column($board, 2));
```

For a diagonal sum, use:

```
$subDiag = array_sum( array_map(function($row, $index){
  return $row[$index];
}, $board, array_keys($board)) );
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks alot this works. Now I only need to find a way to do the diagonal sum

Comment: FYI, an `array_column()` solution for 5.1.0 - 5.4.29: https://coderwall.com/p/v3pxhw (I didn't write it, but did a quick test)

Comment: @hsz I dont think diagonal works, I just checked and returned 0. I tried for `$board[2][3]`

Comment: @GGio diagonal is: [`board[0][0]`, `board[1][1]`, ..., `board[7][7]`] - isn't it ?

Comment: @hsz not only, diagonal from any 1. So Basically goal is You can not have more than one `1` in any diagonal, any row or any column. Row/Columns work now I need diagonal. Im trying to solve 8 queens puzzle slightly different way.